# Auto Removal/Archival of Files in Sharepoint Online in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a requirement to auto remove/archive files of Sharepoint Online Based on some conditions like I need to remove all the files of a particular library which is created or modified on or before 2021 year.

Now can anyone please tell the possible solutions available to do it?

- Should we go through using C# programmatic approach or any other option is there ?
- Can the archival destination be the Azure Blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need any code to accomplish this.
If you want this task to be automated, you can set up automation for your list using power automate (click the "Automate" button on the list toolbar), then configure a (scheduled?) flow to delete/archive old items as you describe (i.e. first select items that are older than 2021, and as the next step use "Delete" action for them). It's a 5-minutes task, no C# or anything. You can also use another action to move the files to azure blob storage, it's a stock action as well. You can start over here:
https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/